# AJAX get id from select field as a variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, select

This is a continuation from a previous question the I made. Basically I'm using  AJAX to call a php insert statement.

This is te bit im stuck on:

**HTML/PHP**

```
    <select name="status" id='000042'>
      <option value=''>--Select--</option>
      <option value='Approve'>Approve</option>
      <option value='Reject'>Reject</option>
      <option value='Pending'>Pending</option>
    </select>
```

**AJAX/JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').on('change',function () {
//$('select').change(function () {
        var statusVal = $(this).val();
        var job_id = $(this).id;
        alert(statusVal);
        $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "saveStatus.php",
                 data: { statusType : statusVal, jobID: job_id },
                 success: function(msg) {
                     $('#autosavenotify').text(msg);
                 }
      })
  });
});
```

The values for `statusVal` get stored just fine and when it calls thee insert statment it works great,
 But the number `i` have used for `id=""` does not store into the ajax variable `job_id`, is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `var job_id = $(this).attr('id');`

Answer (score 3):

Try the below. Use the `.prop` method to access the `id` of the required field.

```
var job_id = $(this).prop('id');
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/pWvfb/)

Comment: Thankyou, Tested this and method below, both work. Thankyou anyway.